# GGplot2 in combination with Guide_legend arguments

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, ggpubr

`theme_pubr` in the `ggpubr` package by default creates legends with the title on the side and the variables distributed horizontally. However,i'm trying to make a legend with the title on top and the species in one column.

I have tried using `guides(colour=guide_legend(ncol=1))` and
`guides(colour = guide_legend(title.position = "top"))` in combination, however one seems to override the other. Can anybody explain why this happens and how to work around it?

example code using the iris dataset.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(datasets)
library(ggpubr)



ggplot(iris,aes(Species, Petal.Length))+
  geom_point(aes(colour= Species))+
  theme_pubr()+
  labs_pubr()+ 
  guides(colour=guide_legend(ncol=1))+
  guides(colour = guide_legend(title.position = "top"))
```

Thanks in advance,

Stuart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating two functions that overwrite each other, you can use both arguments in one function

```
guides(colour=guide_legend(title.position = "top", ncol=1))
```